# how to get values of cell-rendered select of ag-grid in angular 2

Tags: ag-grid

I have rendered cell dropdown of ag-grid. How can I access value of dropdown 
on button click ?

I have tried this

```
cellRenderer: this.EditCellRender.bind(this)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: Post your html code and your js code, it will help other users to answer